# Full text search

Tags: .net, database, full-text-search, search-engine, oracle11g

I am creating a search engine for my own city about service providers in the city. So there can be search for particular keyword or service. Finding data using `LIKE` will affect my
website performance and it is also not a good way. I am using Oracle 11G with .Net and i have
heard about Full text search . Is that a efficient way or is there any other way? In my data base
there is approximate 100,000 rows. if anyone gives answer for sql server 2008 than it is also acceptable.

Please suggest me some optimized way

Comment: Surely full text search gives you much better performances and features than a simple LIKE clause, I know how to use it in SQL Server, for oracle no clue, but should be supported of course.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) is the way to go. It has somewhat of a steep learning curve, but does its job exceptionally well.

StackOverflow search is powered by Lucene.NET.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle Text](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/content.htm#sthref2643) is the built-in full text search option for Oracle.